# Dynamically creating a Type

Tags: c#, reflection, dynamic, types, action

I have the following: `typeof(Action<User, Int32>)` which I need to be able to create dynamically...

I have both of the types I need stored as a `Type` object.

```
Type type1 = ...; // MyNamespace.BusinessObjects.User
Type type2 = ...; // System.Int32

// I need it to be Action<MyNamespace.BusinessObjects.User, System.Int32>
Type action = ? ;
```

Not sure what to do here to get this going.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think this should work:

```
var actionType = typeof(Action<,>).MakeGenericType(type1,type2);
```

Comment: @m-y It was a great question though